# Printing 1D Array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I was trying to print one-dimensional array from another class. But the problem is that  the print statement only prints the same elements.

For example:

Enter total number of customers: 3


Name: Jessica

Age: 22

Gender: female

Name: John

Age: 28

Gender: male

Name: Mike

Age: 35

Gender: male

The outputs that I get from this program are  the same elements of the last customers.

Name-------------Age-----------Gender

Mike                 35                  male

Mike                 35                  male

Mike                 35                  male

Instead I want to get something like:

Name-------------Age-----------Gender

Jessica             22                  female

John                 28                  male

Mike                 35                  male

I do not know what part I am missing or doing incorrectly. I'd really appreciate any feedback!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Customer1234 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    System.out.print("Enter total number of customers: ");
     x = input.nextInt();

    Customer [] customers = new Customer[x];



    Customer.data(customers);

    System.out.println("Name" + "-------------"+ "Age" +"-----------" +"Gender");
    for(int i = 0; i <customers.length; i++){

        System.out.println(customers[i].toString());
    }



}

static class Customer{

    private static String name;
    private static int age;
    private static String gender;


    public Customer(String name, int age, String gender){

        Customer.setName(name);
        Customer.setAge(age);
        Customer.setGender(gender);

    }


    public static void data(Customer [] customers){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < customers.length; i++){

            System.out.print("Name: ");
            setName(input.next());

            System.out.print("Age: ");
            setAge(input.nextInt());

            System.out.print("Gender: ");
            setGender(input.next());

            customers[i] = new Customer( getName(), getAge(), getGender());
        }

    }


    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void setName(String name) {
        Customer.name = name;
    }

    public static int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public static void setAge(int age) {
        Customer.age = age;
    }

    public static String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public static void setGender(String gender) {
        Customer.gender= gender;
    }





    public String toString()
    {
        String result;
        result = name +"         "+ age +"            "+ gender;
        return result;
    }



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `static` everywhere in the Customer class. I would rewrite it as:

```
 private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;


    public Customer(String name, int age, String gender){

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
       this.gender = gender;

    }


    public static void data(Customer [] customers){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < customers.length; i++){

            System.out.print("Name: ");
            setName(input.next());

            System.out.print("Age: ");
            setAge(input.nextInt());

            System.out.print("Gender: ");
            setGender(input.next());

            customers[i] = new Customer( getName(), getAge(), getGender());
        }

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender= gender;
    }





    public String toString()
    {
        String result;
        result = name +"         "+ age +"            "+ gender;
        return result;
    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks hexafraction for your feedback. I did what you suggest me to do but now I am getting error messages  on every print statement  within the data method and mutator(setters) methods. I am sorry, I am new to Java. I apologize for my limited understanding of Java.

Comment: @psSS Change `Customer.whatever` to `this.whatever` everywhere applicable

Answer (score 0):

You're using `static` variables which only allows one value per field for the `Customer` class. Make all the fields instance variables to ensure that a separate value per instance of the class is used

```
class Customer{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;

    ...
}
```